# Images not loading Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a really weird error that started out of nowhere, when I first load the site I get src=Unknown in every Image, but if I resize the page all the images load instantly I have tried everything and nothing seems to work, you can visit the site here [StudioFutbol](http://www.studiofutbol.com.ec) . I use maxcdn, cloudflare and wprocket, could it be something about cache?

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's developer console to search for errors? I can see a load of http status 400, 403, and 451 errors.

Comment: I see you have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

There are some javascript errors that likely are the cause of this issue. It seems it stops lazy loading from functioning correctly on initializing.

Please check the code that adds your google analytics to the pages as there is something wrong for sure in that part.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-20330539-1', 'auto');
      ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
      ga('set', 'dimension2', '<?php the_author(); ?>');
      <?php if (count($categories) > 0) { ?> ga('set', 'dimension3', '<?= $categories[0]->name ?>'); <?php } ?>
      ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I removed the code and it did not help

Comment: I'm still seeing javascript errors in the console, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on line 9 of the index. However it seems to come from javascript combined by WP Rocket. could you try disabling it so we can see where exactly the error comes from ? (pictures should load when disabled as its no longer lazy loading then)

Comment: I'm also still seeing php code output in the html, i did a quick search for **<?php** in the source and i see it still in 8 more palces. my guess there is something more going on

Comment: Indeed it was the js errors, but the problem was a conflict between the rocket loader of cloudflare and some plugin maybe in my site, I disabled the rocket loader and now it is working, now I have to find where the conflict is